# Why does BigQuery user_properties only contain fields with changed values?

Tags: web, google-bigquery, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm currently using the BigQuery streaming export feature of firebase analytics, and I have two questions regarding this.
For reference, my firebase sdk version is 'Web version 9 (modular)'.

1. **Why does BigQuery user_properties only contain fields with changed values?**

In the first event occurred after executing setUserProperties, all user property values are displayed normally in the BigQuery Console. However, all subsequent events do not include any user properties except 'user_id' (even though setUserProperties has never been recalled again.)

I guess that only changed user properties are stored in BigQuery. Is this an intended behavior? Is there any way to always store all user properties in BigQuery?

If there is no way, I would also like to know how to structure the query to see all user_properties for each event in BigQuery.

2. **If the string type data that can be converted to int type is set to properties, BigQuery stores it in int_value field. Can I save it in string_value instead of int_value?**

If I add '1234' to user properties or event properties, it is stored in int_value, not string_value. But I want to store it in string_value. Is there any way to do that?

As mentioned above, I want all custom user_properties to be saved in all custom events.

Also, I want strings like '1234' to be stored in string_value, not int_value.